# Finding source of garbage value

Tags: c, garbage

So I've made a custom code to remove spaces from a string. But when I ran it, if there's no input, the second string will give 3 garbage values, and if there are too many spaces, the code will sometimes add a space string on its own. I  just can't find where the three garbage values come from :(

```
#define SIZE 200
int main ()
{
    int w=0, z=0, x=0, y=0, z0, rDlength=0, Dlength=0, RandomChar, Dx=0, Dy=0;
    char rstring[SIZE], string[SIZE];
    srand(time(NULL));

    //debug
    int space=0;

    printf("Input Text: ");
    gets(rstring);
    strupr(rstring);
    strlen(rstring);
    rDlength=strlen(rstring);

    //debug
    printf("%d\n", rDlength);

    w=-1; 
    for(z=0;z<=rDlength;z++)
    {    if(rstring[z]==' ')
         {   space++;
             continue;
         }
         else if(rstring[z]=='\0')
             break;
         else if(rstring[z]!=' ')
             string[++w]=rstring[z];
    }

    //debug
    printf("%d\n", space);

    Dlength=strlen(string);

    for(z=0;z<rDlength;z++)
        printf("%c", rstring[z]);
    printf("\n");

    for(z=0;z<Dlength;z++)
        printf("%c", string[z]);
    printf("\n");

    printf("String length is %d\n", Dlength);
    return 0;
}
```

If there's at least 3 input characters, then the garbage value seem to disappear. but if there's only two or one character, then the garbage values appear.

Comment: The code is unreadable. Format&indent it properly. Don't get too creative with formatiing.

Comment: You have not terminated `string` the array you are copying char by char to. So `Dlength=strlen(string);` will not give the right answer.

Comment: Oh, Sorry Olaf, I'm very new on this site. What do you mean by indent and format, if I may ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add characters to `string`, you aren't adding a terminating null character.  So any elements of `string` past that are uninitialized.  Calling `strlen` then reads those uninitialized characters resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After copying the characters, add the null terminator to the end:

```
for(z=0;z<=rDlength;z++) {
    if(rstring[z]==' ') {
        space++;
        continue;
    }
    else if(rstring[z]=='\0')
        break;
    else if(rstring[z]!=' ')
        string[++w]=rstring[z];
}
string[++w]='\0';
```

Comment: Oh my, I didn't notice that at all!! Thank you so much!, the code is working well now! Bless you! :D